# Unable to connect to Code branch with update Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220)

Tags: git, xcode7

I am returned "Authentication failed because the user name or password was incorrect." on connecting to GIT code brach with Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220). It was working fine before I updated to 7.